# Number of squarefree numbers and the Basel problem

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, reference-request, prime-numbers, math-history

Who discovered/proved that there are about
$$
\frac{x}{\zeta(2)}
$$
squarefree numbers up to $x$, or (roughly) when was this first known? Today I think this is considered 'obvious', but I don't know if that was always the case.

Was this known before the Basel problem was solved (showing that the sum is $\pi^2/6$)? Perhaps it was known in the form
$$
x\cdot \prod_{n\ge2}\left(1+\frac{\mu(n)}{n^2}\right)
$$
?

Comment: Preety sure that Euler was the first to prove $\zeta(2)=\pi^2/6$ which would predate the Möbius function.

Comment: @TimRaczkowski: Yes, but I'm not asking about when $\zeta(2)=\pi^2/6$ was computed but rather when its application to squarefree numbers was discovered. Did Euler know about that connection when he did his work?

Comment: @Charles: Given the fact that Euler was the first to write the $\zeta$ function as a product over the primes, I'd venture to say yes.